# How to show the tooltip content from partial View In Kendo UI grid?

Tags: jquery, ajax, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

When a mouse is put on the grid cell,I show the tooltip content from partial view using ajax request,but sometimes I find the the tooltip content shows nothing,and sometimes is OK.I try to make the ajax in a synchronous request,but it still not work sometimes.How to fix this?I just want to show the content afer the partial view return.

**In ajax async property:I have try both true or false**

```
$("#Grid").kendoTooltip({
        filter: ".tooltipContent",
        width: "auto",
        position: "top",
        showOn: "click",
        autoHide: false,
        content: function (e) {
            var row = $(e.target).closest("tr");
            var dataItem = $('#Grid').data('kendoGrid').dataItem(row);
            Id = dataItem.Id
            $('#TooltipContentDiv').html("");
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("GetPV","Home")",
                data: { "Id": Id },
                cache: false,
                async: true, 
                success: function (result) {
                     $('#TooltipContentDiv').html(result);
                },
                error: function () { }
            });
            return $('#TooltipContentDiv').html();

        }
    }).data("kendoTooltip");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving your return within the Success event of the Ajax call so that it only returns after a success event (otherwise will be blank). Since JavaScript is asynchronous, it won't wait for the Ajax call to finish, and can fire the **return** before the Success event loads the data.  This may be way you are seeing random results.

```
$("#Grid").kendoTooltip({
    filter: ".tooltipContent",
    width: "auto",
    position: "top",
    showOn: "click",
    autoHide: false,
    content: function (e) {
        var row = $(e.target).closest("tr");
        var dataItem = $('#Grid').data('kendoGrid').dataItem(row);
        Id = dataItem.Id
        $('#TooltipContentDiv').html("");
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("GetPV","Home")",
            data: { "Id": Id },
            cache: false,
            async: true, 
            success: function (result) {
                 $('#TooltipContentDiv').html(result);
            },
            error: function () { }
        });
    }
}).data("kendoTooltip");
```

Comment: Why do you use `return $('#TooltipContentDiv').html();`?May be I can use `return false` or just `return`?

Comment: You're correct.  I updated the answer to reflect it's removal as no return is needed at all.